# Translate a Specific TextView, not all TextViews?

Tags: java, xml, android-studio, spinner, translate

I’m building a language teaching app that needs to translate specific strings but leave all the other strings in the app non-translated. I have a spinner that is populated by all the available languages on android. What I want to do is: when the user selects a language from the spinner, the spinner will select a specific TextView, and translate only that TextView. I have all of my strings translated and stored in their respective strings. Ie. Stings.xml, strings-ar.xml, strings-en.xml.  So I have all the values I need. I just need to be able to use my spinner to select the specific string I want, and to make that string.

So in my code below, I have it set so the top string will be translated to the users locale language, but I want them to be able to use the spinner to select the bottom TextView and have that bottom TextView translated to the language selected in the spinner

```
//spinner array

<string-array name="Languages">
    <item>English</item>
    <item>Arabic</item>
    <item>Bulgarian</item>  etc..
 </string-array>

//xml
<TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/airport" />


    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="217dp"
        android:id="@+id/ImageAirport"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:src="@drawable/airport"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Airport"
        android:id="@+id/textView"/>

//Java

    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener{

    Spinner spinner;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
    ArrayAdapter adapter=ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.Languages, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
    spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);

}

    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i,     long l) {

}

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {

}
}
```